# Why do certain Roslyn symbols have no type information?

Tags: c#, roslyn

This is actually a more general question. I am struggling to understand the conceptual model underlying Roslyn and want to find out more, but am also struggling to find resources.

The specific example I have is that as part of a variable declaration, I iterate over the declarators, and for each declarator I want to know if a conversion occured. It would be nice to have a shared function outside of this one scenario that accepts the symbol/node, checks for the presence of a conversion, and if so does something depending on the symbol typeinfo. Unfortunately, while variable declarations have type info, variable declarators do not.

I do not understand how a variable declarator can have no type. It seems almost random, on a case by case basis when visiting syntax nodes, that I have to check different parent or child nodes to get the type. Can someone shed some light on this and if there is a general approach I could use?

Why does GetConversion return a conversion but has no information on the types involved in the conversion?

Comment: What API are you using with the variable declarators? Normally people get thrown off expecting a declaration to have stuff, but looks like you're on the potential right path here.

Comment: @JasonMalinowski I am using the GetTypeInfo from the semantic model. At least, I was, I ended up just detecting conversion by handling Expressions on the general Visit in the syntax walker. If any Expression gettypeinfo showed a discrepancy between Type and ConvertedType then I injected desired behaviour. Basically GetTypeInfo does not always work - a declarator has no type apparently. (which is interesting because semanticModel.GetConversion on the declarator recognises there was a conversion, but offers no type information, which itself is weird)

Comment: This is somewhat ringing a bell for me but I don't recall the details, but I think that GetTypeInfo() working on a declarator might have been a bit of bug/mistake, since the more logical way for that to work might have instead been you call GetDeclaredSymbol and then get the .Type property off of that. GetTypeInfo is more intended for asking what the resultant type of an expression is that has one, and whether a declaration has a resultant type is a somewhat philosophical question.

Comment: Have you tried looking at using the IOperation APIs? Those tend to be a bit more a representation of the underlying language, and specifically there's an [IConversionOperation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.operations.iconversionoperation?view=roslyn-dotnet-4.3.0) that might give you better what you're looking for.

Comment: @JasonMalinowski Interestingly, Conversion has no info on what types are involved in the conversion.